# Get IP address of visitor after an AJAX form submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have an HTML form. When visitor submits form, a javascript method is invoked.
This method sends an AJAX request to my server's php file.
My problem is i need to get the visitor's ip address. But because of AJAX request calls php file, **$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']** gives me my server's address.
How can i get visitor's ip, in this case?
Thank you

```
<form onsubmit="sendData(); return false;">
    // some data here
</form>

function sendData(){
    // do some work, get variables
    $.ajax({
        url:"/mypage.php",
        type:"GET",
        data: { name: e },
        success : function(data) {
           // do some work
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        }
    })
}

// in mypage.php
public function useData() {
        $name=$_GET["name"];
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Comment: whether a browser issues a request with js (ajax) or a normal page load - the ip address you'll see is the same: that of the client (browser).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will give you the IP address of the client. But since presumably you are using the same machine as server **and** client you get the same IP which is normal. Once you host your website into a web server and access it remotely from a different machine you will get the address of that remote machine.

So there's nothing more you need to do. Your code already works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The ajax request is still originating from the client, it should be giving the clients IP not the servers.

Answer (score 0):

try the code below though modify it as it is meant to run onloading the page, it uses jquery and some free ip api's

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=json", function(data){
    var userIP = data.ip;
    $.getJSON("https://api.ipgeolocationapi.com/geolocate/" + userIP, function(data){
      var userLat = data.geo.latitude;
      var userLng = data.geo.longitude;
      // You can now use the user's latitude and longitude to determine if they're within your geo fence
    });
  });
});
```